# write to firestore after user signs up

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

hello Im trying to write to firestore after a user signs up, It's not showing up on the firestore colelctions where am i going wrong?

the error that comes up is

`"FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined". I've been stuck on this for a few days as I am new to firebase.

thank you! :)

```
export default class Register extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
};

state = {
    name:"",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    errorMessage: null
};


handleSignUp = () => {
    try {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then(function(user){
        const user2 = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        const currentUser = user.uid
    
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('users')
          .doc(user.id)
          .set({
            email: user2.email,
            name: this.state.name
          })
        });
      } catch (err) {
        Alert.alert('There is something wrong!', err.message);
      }
    }
```

Comment: The error message is telling you, quite explicitly, that user.id is undefined.  You may notice in **YOUR OWN CODE** you earlier use user.uid

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you quite explicitly that user.id is undefined.  You may notice in **YOUR OWN CODE** that you earlier used user.uid

So what you're likely looking for is:

```
handleSignUp = () => {
    try {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then(function(user){
        const user2 = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        const currentUser = user.uid
    
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('users')
          .doc(currentUser)
          .set({
            email: user2.email,
            name: this.state.name
          })
        });
      } catch (err) {
        Alert.alert('There is something wrong!', err.message);
      }
    }
```

Comment: hii thank you! I actually just realised that! my problem is the user text input which is this.state.name when a  user logs in , how do i write that to the firebase collection? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Now, Now - that's not the StackOverflow way!  StackOverflow etiquette is you try on your own, find the *specific problem*, and *then* ask ANOTHER question with that specific problem - that way OTHERS with a similar problem can find the question, and hopefully the answer!